# Time $t$ of minimum given rates

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this problem from the 2018 AP Calculus BC FRQ #1:

People enter a line for an escalator at a rate modeled by the function $r$ given by
$$r(t) = \begin{cases} 44(\cfrac t{100})^3 (1-\cfrac t{300})^7 & \text{for 0}\leq t\leq300 \\ \\ 0 &\text{for } t > 300, 
 \end{cases}$$
where $r(t)$ is measured in people per second and $t$ is measured in seconds. As people get on the escalator, they exit the line at a constant rate of $0.7$ people per second. There are $20$ people in line at time $t=0$.

I am confused about part (d) of this question: For $0\leq t\leq300$, at what time $t$ is the number of people in line a minimum? To the nearest whole number, find the number of people in line at this time. Justify your answer.

Here's what I tried. I know that I am going to use the first part of the piecewise that is defined over the interval $[0, 300]$. That equation describes the $\mathbf{rate}$ of change of the people $\mathit entering$. However, I also know that the $\mathbf {rate}$ of change in the number of people $\mathit{leaving}$ is $0.7$ people per second.

I set the rate of people entering as $e(t)$, and the people leaving as $l(t)$. Since these are both rate functions, they are derivatives of the "position" function, or in this case, the number of people on the escalator. By this logic, I would be able to find a critical point by setting the difference of the two derivatives to 0: $$e(t) - l(t)=0$$

When I put in the original equations, I get this equation:
$$44(\cfrac t{100})^3 (1-\cfrac t{300})^7 - 0.7t=0$$

As this is a calculator question, I inputted this equation into my graphing calculator. However, the calculator was unable to solve the equation.

This got me thinking: did I conceptually understand the question incorrectly? After finding the critical point, I would have looked for the change in the derivatives from either side of the point. If the change went from negative to 0 at the critical point, to positive afterward, that would have been my justification for the critical point being a minimum. After reviewing my equations and setup, I seem to not have made a mistake; is it just my calculator being unable to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is almost correct. You are looking for the *rate* of people so you only need to subtract $0.7$ rather than $0.7t$ (which is the *number* of people leaving.) Thus, it would be the equation
$$44\left(\frac{t}{100}\right)^3\left(1-\frac{t}{300}\right)^7-0.7=0$$

After, you can find the *number of people in line* at each of the critical points (including the endpoints). From this, you can find the global minimum (while looking at the derivatives at each point would only give the local minimum).

Comment: Ahhh ok thanks.